# Auto-Assign Unique Value to Names in Two Columns in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a sticky problem that I can't figure out how to do anyway but manually. Maybe you all can help me find a formula that would do this automatically. Here's the set-up.

My organization is currently switching CRM databases, and instead of paying the new CRM for a data upload they have tasked me with uploading the new data. Ok, no big deal, I've done it before, and it's not the worst.

However, the big problem I discovered is that with one of the databases (Raisers Edge NXT) I had to export the whole database out in two sections - one of the constituents and one of the gifts assigned to the constituents. FOR SOME REASON they exported these lists with no unique ID common between them.

So for example - I have a constituent ID for a record in the constituent list and I have a gift record for that constituent but nothing shared between them other than a name, which unfortunately might not be enough for the new Everyaction system to recognize when doing auto-uploads. So my solution is to create a unique Import ID for this import and add a unique ID to every unique name across the consituent and gift record lists so I can run two imports - one of the constituent and then one of the gifts and assign the gifts to the constituents.

Here's the big question how can I assign both lists the same unique IDs without having to go through all 3-4 thousand records manually?

Here's some sample data:

***Sample Data of Problem:***
[image]

Comment: Can you shorten your question and explain logic to gain output? How it comes 6 times `Person F`?

Comment: @harun24hr my guess is Person F made six donations. What I don't understand is what data the leftmost table brings. It seems the rightmost one has every thing in it.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks for the comments. They're making me re-evaluate what I'm doing here. Basically - the database gave me two spreadsheets, the constituent information which is the left column, and the gift information which is the right column. They both share the names, but nothing else, there is no other unique identifier. When I bulk upload them to our new crm I need to first add the constituents and then attach gift records to the constituent record, for this I will be using a unique ID I am creating and attaching to the same name on both spreadsheets. Does that make sense?

Comment: Person F is a recurring donor and donated 6 times. Thus we have multiple gift records for him. @harun24hr

Comment: did my script work? it is one added line to add unique ID #s to left of constituent list too

Comment: @learnAsWeGo thank you for following up. By chance, I was speaking to a friend of mine and he actually offered to do everything I needed in Stata for me. So I didn't end up getting a chance to use your script. Thank you for taking the time to write it out and help me.

Comment: @L.Jaress bummer, glad that it worked out. take care